# Error with XML SpriteFont - Hexadecimal value 0x0 is Illegal in XML Documents

Tags: xml, xna-4.0

I added a character to the character regions of my spritefont, and am receiving the following compiler error for both lines (59 / 60, which are start/end).

```
Character '', hexadecimal value 0x0 is illegal in XML Documents.
```

The only thing I changed in the file was to copy and paste a character region and add the character in question. The game still runs, which i thought odd since an error should have stopped it...?

```
 <CharacterRegions>
      <CharacterRegion>
        <Start>&#32;</Start>
        <End>&#126;</End>
      </CharacterRegion>
      <CharacterRegion>
        <Start>&#9679;</Start>
        <End>&#9679;</End>
      </CharacterRegion>
    </CharacterRegions>
```

Any thoughts on what is wrong with the code above, and why i still compile and run with an error? (VS is set to stop on errors).

Comment: Somewhere in that document, not visible here, there is a null character. That's not legal XML, even in XML 1.1. Find it and fix it.

Comment: Sure enough, I hand typed it instead of copy/paste and it cleared the errors. Any idea why copy and paste would have done that?

Comment: Bug in your tools' copy and paste code? Outside of that, no clue.

Comment: Open the xml in VS, you see the red curly underline. It is probably at the beginning or at the end of the file.